# How to still access a facebook page app after removing it?

Tags: facebook, tabs, uninstallation, favorites

we are creating an app for a facebook page that because of its nature, has to link to other tabs in the same page. So there is a single app that is supposed to link to 4-5 more.
I am trying to only show the parent app in the "favorites" (the place right below the cover picture) and have all the other hidden, so you can only go to them from the parent. I noticed there are 2 options when you hover over each app and click the pencil icon, "remove from favorites" and "uninstall app".

The naming suggests that removing the app from favorites does not uninstall the app from that page. However, that is not the case. After removing an app from the favorites i can no longer access it using its distinct url. So, my question is, what is the difference between these 2 actions and if there is a way to link to apps without the apps showing in the favorites!

Thanks!

Comment: You can get help from Facebook for user / account / site problems at https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=220217228006012 - this is not the correct forum for those questions (see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions  for more information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, my question is, what is the difference between these 2 actions

If you just remove the app from favorites, it’ll still show up in your page management console under “apps”, and an admin can easily re-add it as a page tab from there.

If you uninstall it, however, it’ll be completely removed from your page, even from the management section. (If this also invalidates previously issued page access tokens, I’m not sure – could be.)

> and if there is a way to link to apps without the apps showing in the favorites!

No, not for page tabs.

You could set up your other apps as canvas apps – but then they woulnd’t be in the “context” of your page anymore, meaning that you can not f.e. check easily if the visiting user liked your page or not.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - makes sense! Will check whether a fangate is needed, if not i will go for the canvas option.

Comment: I just removed my app from my page using the "Remove from favorites" link an it doesn't show up anymore in the management console under "apps".